# Door lock hole drilled too big

Tags: doors

I drilled a bigger hole over an existing one on my door so I could put a new lock on. Unfortunately I drilled the hole too big. Now the lock is too to small to install. Any suggestions?

Comment: Interior or exterior? Painted or stained? (I'm assuming wood, but if it's something else, you'll let us know, right?)

Answer (score 2):

Look for reducer or adapter plates. They’re a pair flat rings that go on both sides of the door hole. The outer diameter is big enough to cover the hole completely and the inner diameter is sized for the lock.

They’ll have basic ones at any home store. Usually in brass and satin nickel finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on size and assuming wood, you could cut a plug of the same diameter and glue it in, once dry redrill hole.

Probably only look good with a painted finish or a cover plate...